# Javascript - convert mixed fraction to decimal

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, decimal, eval, fractions

I have a series of recipe ingredients listed like "1-1/2" which I need to change to a proper number like "1.5" in order to calculate according to serving sizes. How do I change the mixed fraction to a decimal number? I've seen the eval function, which works for things like "1/2", but for something like "1-1/2" it evaluates it as ".5".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: Add your safety checks (like ensuring there is a "-" in the input etc.)

**Code**:

```
function toDecimal(_x) {
   var parts = _x.split("-");
   var decParts = parts[1].split("/");
   return parseInt(parts[0], 10) + 
             (parseInt(decParts[0], 10) / parseInt(decParts[1], 10));
}
var x = "1-1/2";
console.log(toDecimal(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "-" is your separator, you could come up with something like the following, when you use [fraction.js](https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js):

```
function getDecimal(str) {
    var f, s = str.split("-");

    if (s.length > 1) {
        f = new Fraction(s[0]).add(s[1]);
    } else {
        f = new Fraction(str);
    }
    return f.valueOf();
}
console.log(getDecimal("1-1/2")); // 1.5
console.log(getDecimal("1/2")); // 0.5
```